# How to go to a specific line to check the condition again?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

```py
if net.res_bus.vm_pu[self.bus]  > 1.005 :
                     self.p_mw = self.p_mw + self.data_source.get_time_step_value(time_step=time,profile_name=self.p_profile)
                     self.soc_percent += ((self.data_source.get_time_step_value(time_step=time,profile_name=self.p_profile)*15/60)/self.max_e_mwh) * 100
```

I am using the pandapower package in Python. Here, I need to check a condition, if it is true I need to perform some calculations and after doing the calculations I need to check it again, and this should go until it is true. So, here I need to go to the if condition again after the calculations. How can I do that? I tried for loop, it is getting messed up somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean if it is false then do the calculation?  Use ```While```    While variable == false:

Comment: No. If it is true, do the calculation and check the condition again till it becomes false. And should come out of that if condition, once it is false.

Comment: May be just changing if to while might work I guess.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a python [`while` loop.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp)

You could structure your code like this, replacing the `if` with a `while`:

```py
while net.res_bus.vm_pu[self.bus] > 1.005 :
    self.p_mw = self.p_mw + self.data_source.get_time_step_value(time_step=time,profile_name=self.p_profile)
    self.soc_percent += ((self.data_source.get_time_step_value(time_step=time,profile_name=self.p_profile)*15/60)/self.max_e_mwh) * 100
```

Without understanding your code better, I don't see anywhere that the value of `net.res_bus.vm_pu[self.bus]` is changed. If that is the case, you may want to check a different variable in the `while`